# Canvas trying to draw too large bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-viewpager, android-drawable

I am getting an issue when I try to load set of images in View Pager in Android N (checking Samsung S6).

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap.
>
> Image dimension is 960*720 and its size 64 k, View Pager count is 4

Now I place all the images in normal "drawable" folder. I tried by replacing all the images to "drawable-xxhdpi" but the issue still exist.

Comment: does this issue fixed?

Answer (score 6):

Im my case i resolved it by going to my manifest and changing `hardwareAccelerated` from `true` to `false`. `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`,

Comment: This worked for me capturing a 3:4 ration 64MP image using a Samsung s21 device. However, what are the implications of setting hardwareAccelerated to false?

Answer (score 1):

Nougat is pretty smart in optimisation. It doesn't matter in whichever drawable directory you put it in. It will detect whether the image is suitable for the fluent working of the app or not. And if it is not then it will generate this exception.

**Solution:**

1. Use [Final android Resizer](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer) to generate drawables for all dpi.
2. Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to load bitmaps efficiently (it supports bitmap caching and bitmap pooling).
3. If your image is of single coloured (like icons) then you can generate vector drawables from .SVG or .PSD files. Learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).

Good luck :D